# bufferedinputstream help

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I saw the following code somewhere and I'm confused by the (ry-'0') part. what does that do? bis is a buffered input stream and the input is a line of multiple integers that are each separated by a space(ie. 1 2 3 4 5 6).

```
static int num()throws IOException{
  rz=0;
  while((ry=bis.read())<'0' || ry>'9'){}
  rz+=(ry-'0');
  while((ry=bis.read())>='0' && ry<='9')
   rz=rz*10+(ry-'0');
  return rz;
 }
```

Comment: If bis is at the end of file, it will go into an endless loop.  A much better approach would be to read the text and use standard split(" ") and Integer.parseInt() methods. Much less cryptic and almost as fast.

Comment: `Scanner` would be a better choice.

Comment: Agree with Peter Lawrey. This is very poor code.

Answer (score 3):

`ry-'0'` converts the ASCII character '0'-'9' stored in `ry` to the corresponding decimal value (0-9).

'0' is converted to 0, '1' to 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

aix' answer is correct, but let me add a small explanation:

It's important to look at the types of the different entities of the expression `ry-'0'` in order to understand it. Well, perhaps even before that we have to realize that we are looking at a *subtraction*, i.e, at an expression or the kind *x minus y* where *x* is `ry` and *y* is `'0'`

`ry` is an `int`, `0` is a `char`. In Java it is possible to upward-cast `char` to `int`. For an arithmetic expression like *x - y* to be work, *x* and *y* have to be of the same type. In your case you have

```
ry - '0'
```

that is, `int - char` as far as types are concerned. Thus, your Java VM will automagically cast the char to int, which will make both arguments of the minus match typewise. That is also the reason why the returned value is of type `int`. You can check that by changing the declaration of rz from `int rz` to `char rz`: the compile will then complain that you're trying to assign a `int` (the result of the subtraction) to a `char` variable (rz) without an explicit cast.